# Automaticaly export Jobs and stored procedure from mssql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have MS SQL server with several jobs. Sometimes I and my colleagues change task. I want to export jobs, like at  [image] automaticaly so that put in mercurial and store version of jobs.
I would also like to have a similar opportunity for stored procedures in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you realize that SSMS is using SMO (Server Management Objects) to do the scripting, and that you can use SMO yourself directly through something like powershell, this sort of thing gets easy. For instance, here's scripting out all the jobs on your server (written in powershell):

```
pushd;
import-module sqlps -disablenamechecking;
popd;

$s = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server 'yourServer';
$db = $s.Databases['yourDatabase'];
foreach ($proc in $db.StoredProcedures | where {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $false}) {
   $proc.script();
}

$a = $s.JobServer;
foreach ($job in $a.Jobs) {
   $job.script();
}
```

This is the least fancy version in that it dumps it straight to your screen. Want fancier? Create a [ScriptingOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions_properties.aspx) object and pass that to the `script()` method. That should get you started.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip.
But your example on line 
`$s = new-object sql.microsoft.sqlserver.managment.smo.server 'yourServer';`
 I gave  error:
`New-Object : Cannot find type [sql.microsoft.sqlserver.managment.smo.server]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.`
I changed the code a bit and got a working example.

Comment: Ack... Typo. Fixed.

Comment: It is the tragedy of a single character :-)
I spent an hour on the alternative solution for this problem.

Comment: I found alternative solution for export stored procedure - `sp_helptext 'stored_procedure_name'`

Answer (score 0):

In my case this example worked without error, thanks Ben Thul:

```
import-module sqlps -disablenamechecking;

$jobs = Get-ChildItem sql\ServerName\default\jobserver\jobs
foreach ($job in $jobs) {
    Write-host $job.Name #script();
    $job.script()|out-file c:\out\jobs\$job.sql UTF8
}


import-module sqlps -disablenamechecking;

$StoredProcedures = Get-ChildItem sql\ServerName\default\Databases\DatabaseName\StoredProcedures
foreach ($sp in $StoredProcedures) {
    $spname=$sp.Schema+"."+$sp.Name
    Write-host $sp.Name #script();
    $sp.script()|out-file c:\out\sp\$spname.sql UTF8
}
```

Comment: Homework for you: get it to write each job/procedure to its own file. Hint: the ScriptingOptions object has a FileName property on it. Since you're ultimately putting this in version control, I think you'll find one file per object a bit more manageable. But excellent work!

Comment: I did so - $job and $spname is variable. But I understood you about more simple use with script() and FileName.

Comment: Ah... so you did! I missed the dollar sign in front of the output file name. It seems that we're trading meaningful one-character differences. :)